# Remove underline from hover in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, underline

I added a hoverboard on my site that flips over to reveal more text. It only works well with Chrome, so I tried turning it off in Firefox. It doesn't flip anymore in Firefox, but it makes the box have a gray underline on hover.

I just can't figure out which CSS is having this effect.

My site is:

(removed) - hover over "Sort Products By Availability" to see what I'm referring to.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You're only using `-webkit-` prefixes in [89e843b0.5175cb.css](http://outgrow.me/wp-content/w3tc/min/89e843b0.5175cb.css), which results in other browsers not displaying this element with rounded corners, perpective directives, etc.

When necessary, use [`-moz-`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Reference/Mozilla_Extensions), [`-ms-`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673536%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `-o-`, as well as unprefixed properties.

For an exhaustive list of prefixed properties in all browsers, see http://peter.sh/experiments/vendor-prefixed-css-property-overview/.

Answer (score 1):

[That stylesheet](http://outgrow.me/wp-content/w3tc/min/89e843b0.5175cb.css) Remove background:#ddd from **#hover-flip:hover**

Comment: Works, but not all the way. There's still small gray line on either side.

Comment: At that same div, there is property "box-shadow". Removing it as well, will make those gray lines disappear as well.